# Determine if absolutely convergent, conditionally convergent or divergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n2^n+1}{3^n+n^2}x^n$

I have tried to do the limit comparison test:

$$\frac{\frac{n2^n+1}{3^n+n^2}x^n}{\frac{2^n}{3^n}}$$

but I don't think this will lead me anywhere. In general I'm looking for a hint as to how to approach the problem, not the whole solution.

Comment: $\frac{n2^n+1}{2\cdot 3^n}<\frac{n2^n+1}{3^n+n^2}<\frac{n2^n+1}{3^n}$

Comment: Root test, also, gives direct answer.